# Power Barrel Connector Voltage Rating Inquiry

Tags: connector, datasheet, high-voltage

My system is using 48V at 3A max. I am currently looking for a power connector to my PCB that can handle my specifications. I came across a potential connector, but I noticed on the data sheet it is rated for 24VDC and 5A. How does the manufacturer determine the voltage rating? Could I get away with using it at 48V if I am well below the current rating?

Part of interest: PJ-037BH-SMT-TR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet for that part lists 24V as typical, not maximum.  You will not have any issues at 48V.